# sometimes crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS with no message (set NSZombieEnabled)

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access, nszombie, remoteio

I'm handling RemoteIO to get mic inputs and modify them little.

Sometimes it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and there is no more message.

The lines that make crashes are these;

```
  int currPower = [[powers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
  int prevPower = [[powers objectAtIndex:i - 1] intValue];
```

explaining the code,

1. "powers" is `NSMutableArray`.
2. `[powers count]` was always **bigger** than variable "i"

Struggling for a while, I found a good way to fix it.

A environment variables.

So I set `NSZombieEnabled` and also `NSDebugEnabled` so that I could see the reason of the crashes.

But even though I set the variables, Xcode shows no message.
(But it correctly shows messages when a crash occurs from other line.)

Also a weird thing is that it doesn't crash just after the start of run;
it crashes in a minute in average. (But the times really varied.)

And this is a little guess. When I decreased the rate to half than before,
it was more stable.

So, is it a problem with `NSMutableArray`, because `NSMutableArray` method couldn't catch up the speed of the rate?

or do you see some other possible reasons?

=========================================================================================

There are some more codes.
I allocated powers in this way..

```
  powers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:POWER_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

where I release the powers array is..

```
  - (void)dealloc {
     [powers release];
     [super dealloc];
  }
```

and no where else.

more detailed code is this.

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  { 
     ...//Do Something
     ...//Check "endindex" and "startindex" not to exceed boundary

     for (int i = endindex; i > startindex; i-=1)
     {

        int currPower = [[powers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        int prevPower = [[powers objectAtIndex:i - 1] intValue];

        ...//Doing something

     }
  }
```

**this drawRect: method is calling from Main Thread(By Timer) in every millisecond.**

--
updating(more specifically adding) powers in this method

```
  - (void)setPower:(int)p
  {

     [powers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:p]]; 

     while ([powers count] > POWER_ARRAY_SIZE){
        [powers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     }
  }
```

and also this method is calling in every millisecond.
and this is calling in background thread.

so without @autoreleasepool XCode Shows message of alert of leaking

for this reason I blocked the method(setPower) with @autoreleasepool{..}

Comment: What if i = 0 ? i-1 < 0 and you would be trying to access object out of bounds of Array. And post code related to powers array. Where its allocated and where are you releasing it.

Comment: @whitelionV u meant "Automatic Reference Counting"? No I don't use it! what is it?

Comment: @0x8badf00d I posted more codes, is it more helpful? and I'm sorry i don't understand the if i = 0 ? i-1 < 0 thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Crashes are occurred because NSMutableArray of objected-C sometimes ack wrong.

That's when I try to do something in every milliseconds with it.

So I changed the Objective-C array to C array, like

```
  int power[ARRAYSIZE];
```

and after I changed it, it works fine.

May be NSMutableArray isn't that light to do something really fast.

Answer (score 0):

If NSZombies solved your problem it means that your `NSMutableArray` is being released somewhere, or it's in an autorelease pool. Also you could be trying to write outside the bounds of your array.

- If the `NSMutableArray` is in an autorelease pool (it was created by a convenience method or you explicitly `autorelease`d it) manually `retain` it and `release` it when you no longer need it.
- If the object is not in an autorelease pool check when the `release` is called for that object.
- Write a simple warning before the assignment:

`if( i <= 0 || i >= [powers count] ) NSLog(@"Here's the problem. i = %d", i);`

Comment: I posted more codes. thank you for the answers, but as i checked for the answers, and put the code u wrote and tested, problem occurs same as before.